# Who are the members of Team Jiraiya?

Tags: naruto

I know only Minato Namikaze (The Fourth Hokage). Who are the other two members of Team Jiraiya?

Answer (score 2):

As of right now there is no information disclosed about the other two members of [Team Jiraiya](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Team_Jiraiya).

> This was a genin team led by Jiraiya of the Legendary Sannin at some point after he left the Ame Orphans and returned to Konohagakure. Its only known member is Minato Namikaze, who Jiraiya took special interest in. Minato would later become the Fourth Hokage. **The names of the other two members, as well as their statuses, are unknown.**

However we did actually see one according to the wiki:

> In a flashback that Kushina Uzumaki had, one of Minato's black-haired teammate can be seen sitting behind him at the Academy.

Comment: Can we consider the other members of the team to be in the Naruto Shippuden Movie 5? When Naruto met his father?

Comment: By the look from the picture here http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Team_Jiraiya, we could say one of the team member was from Nara clan.

Answer (score 0):

The name and details of the rest of the team was never revealed in the original manga. However we may assume that they were very talented to be taught by Jiraiya.